# Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'. in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-test

THE ANSWER IS POSTED IN THE COMMENTS

so I am getting this error when I try to run the `flutter run`

Here is my `flutter run -v`

```
[ +400 ms] executing: [C:\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[ +200 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +2 ms] 9b2d32b605630f28625709ebd9d78ab3016b2bf6
[   +2 ms] executing: [C:\flutter/] git tag --points-at HEAD
[ +189 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at HEAD
[        ] 1.22.6
[  +11 ms] executing: [C:\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +59 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +1 ms] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [C:\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +45 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +89 ms] executing: [C:\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +69 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +1 ms] stable
[ +109 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +8 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +40 ms] executing: C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +79 ms] List of devices attached
           emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86 model:sdk_gphone_x86 device:generic_x86_arm
           transport_id:1
[  +15 ms] C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
[  +68 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +8 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +654 ms] Generating
C:\Users\risha\development\flutter\willtenn\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +65 ms] ro.hardware = ranchu
[  +40 ms] Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling
software
           rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
[  +57 ms] Starting incremental build...
[  +11 ms] Initializing file store
[  +37 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[  +30 ms] complete
[  +14 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
[  +22 ms] C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev
C:\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
C:\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names
--experimental-emit-debug-metadata -Ddart.developer.causal_async_stacks=true --output-dill
C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.3ced7550\flutter_tool.c5ea3fda\app.dill --packages .packages
-Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false
--bytecode-options=source-positions,local-var-info,debugger-stops,instance-field-initializers,keep-unreachable-code,avoi
d-closure-call-instructions --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root
--initialize-from-dill build\cache.dill.track.dill
[  +39 ms] executing: C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.2\aapt dump xmltree
C:\Users\risha\development\flutter\willtenn\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[  +68 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.2\aapt dump xmltree
C:\Users\risha\development\flutter\willtenn\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[   +5 ms] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="10" (Raw: "10")
               A: package="com.example.willtenn" (Raw: "com.example.willtenn")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1d
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0xa
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x10
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: application (line=22)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="willtenn" (Raw: "willtenn")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" (Raw:
                 "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw:
                 "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: activity (line=28)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.willtenn.MainActivity" (Raw:
                   "com.example.willtenn.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=42)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" (Raw:
                     "io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0a0001
                   E: meta-data (line=52)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" (Raw:
                     "io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f040000
                   E: intent-filter (line=56)
                     E: action (line=57)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=59)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw:
                       "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=66)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
[  +32 ms] executing: C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat
-v time -t 1
[ +121 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x
logcat -v time -t 1
[   +4 ms] --------- beginning of main
           06-29 22:35:20.130 E/wifi_forwarder(  490): RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to
           open pipe
[   +5 ms] executing: C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat
-v time -t 1
[ +118 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x
logcat -v time -t 1
[   +4 ms] --------- beginning of main
           06-29 22:35:20.130 E/wifi_forwarder(  490): RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to
           open pipe
[  +45 ms] <- compile package:willtenn/main.dart
[  +66 ms] executing: C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[ +123 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
                    Version 30.0.4-6686687
                    Installed as C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[   +6 ms] executing: C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[  +79 ms] Building APK
[  +32 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[   +4 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
[  +11 ms] Using gradle from C:\Users\risha\development\flutter\willtenn\android\gradlew.bat.
[   +3 ms] C:\Users\risha\development\flutter\willtenn\android\gradlew.bat mode: 33279 rwxrwxrwx.
[  +27 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[ +155 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[   +1 ms] openjdk version "1.8.0_242-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b01, mixed mode)
[   +7 ms] executing: [C:\Users\risha\development\flutter\willtenn\android/]
C:\Users\risha\development\flutter\willtenn\android\gradlew.bat -Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-x86
-Ptarget=C:\Users\risha\development\flutter\willtenn\lib\main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true
-Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[+4555 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE
[   +3 ms] > Task :app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[  +81 ms] > Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[   +2 ms] > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED
[   +1 ms] 4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
[   +4 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +4 ms] * What went wrong:
[   +3 ms] Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
[   +2 ms] > java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
C:\Users\risha\development\flutter\willtenn\build\app\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\example\willtenn
[   +2 ms] * Try:
[   +1 ms] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log
output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[   +2 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[   +1 ms] BUILD FAILED in 4s
[ +618 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 5.5s)
[  +22 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +9 ms] "flutter run" took 7,496ms.
[  +21 ms]
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:607:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:977:18)
           #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #11     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
           #12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #18     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #19     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #20     AndroidDevice.isLocalEmulator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart)
           #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #23     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #24     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #25     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #26     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #27     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
           #28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
           #31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
           #32     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
           #33     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
           #34     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
           #35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)


[ +200 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 179ms
[   +3 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[   +2 ms] Shutdown hook priority 4
[   +4 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] exiting with code 1
```

Here is my `flutter doctor -v`

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.22.6 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (5 months ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Android
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin installed
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.23.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

I have been looking for a solution for about two weeks now, and I still have not found the problem. Thank you for any help!

THE ANSWER IS POSTED IN THE COMMENTS

Comment: Looks like your problem could be there: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
C:\Users\risha\development\flutter\willtenn\build\app\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\example\willtenn , looks like flutter have no permission to write in this directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the whole problem, by deleting the folder "build" in the project file.

Answer (score 2):

Run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` commands in your project folder